# Issue with GtkButton signal callback not being triggered for "Confirm" button in modal window

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3, gtk4

I'm working on a GTK4 application where I have a modal window with an "Add Item" form. The modal window includes an entry form and a "Confirm" button. For some reason, the signal callback for the "Confirm" button is not being triggered when the button is clicked.

1. I'm using Glade for UI design.
2. Other buttons in the main window trigger their respective callbacks successfully.
3. The "Confirm" button is placed inside a GtkDialog (modal window).
4. When I click the "Confirm" button, I expect to see the confirmation message, but nothing happens.

code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "tov.h"

// Forward declarations of signal handlers
void on_button_add_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data);
void on_button_delete_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data);
void on_button_show_content_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data);
void on_button_modify_content_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data);
void on_button_confirm_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data);

// ...

// Activation callback
static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *modal_window;
    GtkWidget *button_add, *button_delete, *button_show_content, *button_modify_content, *confirm_button;

    // Initialize your TOV file (replace with actual initialization)
    FichierTOV *fichier = g_malloc(sizeof(FichierTOV));
    initialiserFichierTOV(fichier, MAX_ENREGISTREMENTS);

    // Create a new builder from the Glade file
    builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("design.glade");

    // Get the main window and buttons from the builder
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "main_window"));
    button_add = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_add"));
    button_delete = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_delete"));
    button_show_content = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_show_content"));
    button_modify_content = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_modify_content"));
    confirm_button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_confirm"));

    if (!window || !button_add || !button_delete || !button_show_content || !button_modify_content || !confirm_button)
    {
        g_printerr("Failed to fetch widgets from the Glade file\n");
        g_object_unref(builder);
        return;
    }

    // Set the application for the window and connect signals
    gtk_window_set_application(GTK_WINDOW(window), app);

    // Connect signals
    g_signal_connect(button_add, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_add_clicked), window);
    g_signal_connect(button_delete, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_delete_clicked), fichier);
    g_signal_connect(button_show_content, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_show_content_clicked), fichier);
    g_signal_connect(button_modify_content, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_modify_content_clicked), fichier);

    // Create the modal window
    modal_window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "add_item_modal"));

    if (!modal_window)
    {
        g_printerr("Failed to fetch modal window from the Glade file\n");
        g_object_unref(builder);
        return;
    }

    // Set the modal window for the "Confirm" button
    g_signal_connect(confirm_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_confirm_clicked), modal_window);

    // Show the main window
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));

    // Release the builder
    g_object_unref(builder);
}

// Signal handler for the "Add" button
void on_button_add_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    printf("Add button was clicked\n");
    GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file("design.glade");
    GtkWidget *modal_window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "add_item_modal"));

    // Set parent window for the modal
    GtkWindow *parent_window = GTK_WINDOW(user_data);
    gtk_window_set_transient_for(GTK_WINDOW(modal_window), parent_window);

    // Present the modal window using gtk_window_present
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(modal_window));
    g_object_unref(builder);
}

void on_button_confirm_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *modal_window = GTK_WIDGET(user_data);
    printf("Confirm button was clicked\n");
    // Additional logic...
}

void on_button_modify_content_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    printf("Modify Content button was clicked\n");
}

void on_button_show_content_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    printf("Show Content button was clicked\n");
}

void on_button_delete_clicked(GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{
    printf("Delete button was clicked\n");
}

// Add your other functions here...

// Your file I/O functions and other logic...

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    // Create a new application
    app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);

    // Connect the activation signal to the activation callback
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);

    // Start the application
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);

    g_object_unref(app);
    return status;
}
```

Glade UI Description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="4.0"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main_window">
    <property name="title">File Manager</property>
    <property name="default-width">600</property>
    <property name="default-height">400</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="vbox_main">
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">10</property>
        <!-- Vertical Box for displaying content and buttons -->
        <child>
          <!-- Label for displaying content -->
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label_content">
            <property name="width-request">580</property>
            <property name="height-request">600</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="label">[Content will be displayed here]</property>
            <property name="wrap">true</property>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <!-- Horizontal Box for buttons -->
          <object class="GtkBox" id="hbox_buttons">
            <property name="homogeneous">true</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button_add">
                <property name="label">Add</property>
                <property name="width-request">150</property> <!-- Increase width -->
                <property name="height-request">100</property> <!-- Increase height -->
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button_delete">
                <property name="label">Delete</property>
                <property name="width-request">150</property> <!-- Increase width -->
                <property name="height-request">100</property> <!-- Increase height -->
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button_show_content">
                <property name="label">Show Content</property>
                <property name="width-request">150</property> <!-- Increase width -->
                <property name="height-request">100</property> <!-- Increase height -->
              </object>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="button_modify_content">
                <property name="label">Modify Content</property>
                <property name="width-request">150</property> <!-- Increase width -->
                <property name="height-request">100</property> <!-- Increase height -->
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>

  <object class="GtkDialog" id="add_item_modal">
    <property name="title">Add Item</property>
    <property name="modal">True</property>
    <child>
        <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
        <object class="GtkBox" id="modal_box">
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <property name="margin-start">10</property>
            <property name="margin-end">10</property>
            <property name="margin-top">10</property>
            <property name="margin-bottom">10</property>
            <child>
                <object class="GtkLabel" id="first_name_label">
                    <property name="label">Enter first name:</property>
                </object>
            </child>
            <child>
                <object class="GtkEntry" id="first_name_entry"/>
            </child>
            <child>
                <object class="GtkLabel" id="second_name_label">
                    <property name="label">Enter second name:</property>
                    <property name="margin-top">10</property>
                </object>
            </child>
            <child>
                <object class="GtkEntry" id="second_name_entry"/>
            </child>
            <child>
                <object class="GtkLabel" id="id_label">
                    <property name="label">Enter ID (numbers only):</property>
                    <property name="margin-top">10</property>
                </object>
            </child>
            <child>
                <object class="GtkEntry" id="id_entry"/>
            </child>
            <child>
                <object class="GtkButton" id="button_confirm">
                    <property name="label">Confirm</property>
                    <property name="margin-top">20</property>
                </object>
            </child>
        </object>
    </child>
</object>
</interface>
```

how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the scope of variables/objects.
The following should be included in the on_button_add_clicket function.

```
GtkWidget *confirm_button; 
confirm_button = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "button_confirm"));
// Create the modal window
    modal_window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "add_item_modal"));

    if (!modal_window)
    {
        g_printerr("Failed to fetch modal window from the Glade file\n");
        g_object_unref(builder);
        return;
    }

    // Set the modal window for the "Confirm" button
    g_signal_connect(confirm_button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_confirm_clicked), modal_window);
```

Of course, it should be deleted in its original location.